# StringRequest store data after post

Tags: android, database, post, response

I have a problem, when I click on the `button`, the id is always null on the first click, but gets id on the next clicks. 
This is the code

```
    public class MainActivity
    extends AppCompatActivity implements  view.OnClickListener {

    private Button buttonRegister;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonRegister=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    String userID="null";//i create user id
    final String URL = "https://aiman-king961.rhcloud.com/findID.php";//my url

    public String SimplePotRequest(){       StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    userID=response;//this is how i store it
                    //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    System.out.println(response);



                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            }){

        @Override

        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError //i know this to pass the parameter
        {
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            map.put("username","hasanal");//this is how i try
            return map;
        }
    };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        return userID;
    };

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String id=SimplePotRequest();

        if(v==buttonRegister){

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
   }
```

The point is I want to store userID inside id when I click, because I want to use it in other function, this is part of my login system in `android`

Comment: This is happening because your view has not been rendered yet on your first click, as you might be doing some background job and while you click the next time view has been rendered and it can find id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below code, May be solved your problems:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

   private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://simplifiedcoding.16mb.com/UserRegistration/volleyRegister.php";

   public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
   public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
   public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

   private EditText editTextUsername;
   private EditText editTextEmail;
   private EditText editTextPassword;

   private Button buttonRegister;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextEmail= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);

        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void registerUser(){
    final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
            params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
            params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == buttonRegister){
        registerUser();
     }
  }
}
```

Note : [sample source code](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-post-request-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the function you are calling probably is asynchronous.

First time you push the button, the function is called in background. The id variable is still `null` when the toast is shown.

The second time that you push the button, the id variable is filled by the first request. A second call has run in background, but the id is showed with the previous data.

To manage the problem you need to wait until the call is finished. Make your actions in your `onResponse`

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    userID=response;//this is how i store it
    //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    System.out.println("apekk"+response);
    buttonRegister.setText(response);

    // Make your actions here
}
```

Comment: i cant do that, becouse i want to access it from button bellow, store it in a varievle

Comment: You can do it from de button. User push button -> Start request and show progressBar -> onResponse fill the variable and hide the progressbar. That's it. Is the way to manage an asynchronous request.